# Cookie overwrite / renew not working?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm having hard times overwriting a cookie and its a little bit unclear to me, why the cookie is not being updated.

- I'm having a single page application.
- On SignIn a post request authenticates user and sets cookie with response headers

  set-cookie:token=theinitialtoken; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 08 Mar 2017 16:34:30 GMT
- On every consecutive request I'd like to renew the cookie with response headers.

  set-cookie:token=renewedtoken; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 08 Mar 2017 16:34:31 GMT

Page is not being reloaded in between. Its same origin. The cookie is set with exactly the same nodejs express code. The first cookie makes it into the cookie storage. However the renewed token never updates the original one.

Cookies are send with:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
//res.clearCookie('token');
res.cookie('token', refreshed_token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + (config.token_expire * 1000)),
    httpOnly: false,
    // secure: false,
    secure: true,
    domain: req.hostname
});
```

I'm not understanding why the cookie is not updated since name, domain and path are exactly the same?

Comment: How are you updating your token, is the API on the same domain? Following code should update the token if you make a request `res.cookie("token", "1234");`.

Comment: @RistoNovik added information.  Its same domain, so no CORS issues should occur.

Comment: What is the response of curl using verbose flag, does the cookie get set? `curl -X POST  "https://example.com/api/token/" -k -v`